# $f( \phi^{-1}(x_0 +h)) = f(\phi^{-1}(x_0+h))+h \alpha+ O(h^2)$ - value of $\alpha$

Tags: limits, continuity, inverse-function

Consider a function (continuous) $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $M$ a $1$-dimensional manifold, and suppose some (smooth) chart $\phi : T \to \mathbb{R}$ having an (smooth) inverse on some open $(x_0- \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and that when **(1)** $h \to 0$ : $f( \phi^{-1}(x_0 +h)) = f(\phi^{-1}(x_0))+h \alpha+ O(h^2)$. Is there anyone could be able to explain how to obtain **(1)** and what could be the value of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Taylor expansion of the function in local coordinates. You should prove that in fact $f$ is $C^1$, not just continuous, and $\alpha$ should be the derivative.

Comment: his problem is how to define the differential in a manifold (and then how to define the Laplacian operator) and I was trying to show him how the knowledge of the differential of $f$ in some local coordinates chart $\phi$ can be used for knowing the differential in every other charts.

Comment: at the end, the target is to explain how the metric lets us avoiding defining a "first chart" and finding a definition of the differential operators that is the same up to every change of charts

Comment: @user1952009 I apologize, I'll solve the rest of the problem rigorously by myself and introduce you.